# Generic Cache struct

Tags: rust

I've came up with the following implementation of a very simple cache:

```rust
use std::cmp::Eq;
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::hash::Hash;

pub struct Cache<I, R, F>
    where I: Copy + Eq + Hash, F: Fn(I) -> R
{
    calculation: F,
    values: HashMap<I, R>,
}

impl<I, R, F> Cache<I, R, F> where I: Copy + Eq + Hash, F: Fn(I) -> R {
    pub fn new(calculation: F) -> Cache<I, R, F> {
        Cache { calculation, values: HashMap::new() }
    }
    pub fn value(&mut self, arg: I) -> &R {
        // Pop or calculate new value
        let result = match self.values.remove(&arg) {
            Some(v) => v,
            None => (self.calculation)(arg)
        };
        // Store value
        self.values.insert(arg, result);
        // Return a reference to it
        self.values.get(&arg).unwrap()
    }
}
```

A simple usage example would be:

```rust
fn to_lowercase(value: &str) -> String {
    println!("Calculating \"{}\".to_lowercase()", value);
    value.to_lowercase()
}

fn main() {
    let mut cache = Cache::new(to_lowercase);
    println!("Calculated: {}", cache.value("ABC"));
    println!("Calculated: {}", cache.value("ABC"));
}
```

Which prints:

```
Calculating "ABC".to_lowercase()
Calculated: abc
Calculated: abc
```

However, I feel like my code is much more complicated than it needs to be (specially around the `Cache.value` implementation), what can be improved here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The biggest change you can do is to the value function. Because most of what you are building is actually provided via `HashMap`'s[`entry`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.entry) API. This could reduce the body of your value function to simply this:

```
match self.values.entry(arg) {
    Entry::Occupied(val) => val.into_mut(),
    Entry::Vacant(slot) => slot.insert((self.calculation)(arg)),
}
```

You could also mess with `Entry`'s [`or_insert_with`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/hash_map/enum.Entry.html#method.or_insert_with) function, but I personally prefer the approach above.

You may also consider using [`Clone`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/clone/trait.Clone.html) instead of [`Copy`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Copy.html). The advantage of `Clone` are that it is more explicit and that it should support more types. The disadvantage obviously is that `clone` can be arbitrarily expensive. In general I'd say you want `Clone` for a generic interface such as this.

Finally, I understand it's an exercise, but the names are a bit plain:

- `Cache` is very generic: what do you actually cache? Call it something like `FunctionResultCache` or [`Memoizer`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization)
- `value` is also a bit weird. What you're doing in essence is wrapping a function, so I'd name this `call` or `invoke` or something similar.